# Does numpy provide methods for fundamental matrix operations?

Tags: numpy, matrix

Namely, rearranging rows, adding multiples of rows, and multiplying by scalars.

I don't see these methods defined in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html or elsewhere.

And if they aren't defined, then why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can manipulate array rows, adding and multiplying them.  For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: m = np.ones((3, 4))

In [3]: m
Out[3]:
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [4]: m[1, :] = 2*m[1, :]  # Multiply

In [5]: m
Out[5]:
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [6]: m[0, :] = m[0, :] + 2*m[1, :] # Multiply and add

In [7]: m
Out[7]:
array([[ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [8]: m[ (0, 2), :] = m[ (2, 0), :]  # Swap rows

In [9]: m
Out[9]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]])
```

Comment: D'oh. It's ok though because, lacking something better to do, I wrote my own module for them in the meantime.